is there a way to end all the processes when using multiprocessing in python?
I'm new to python and I would like to find a way to see if i can end all the processes at once when i get my wanted result and put it inside one of the processes. I tried many things like sys.exit() and other stuff but it never works.
This is my code
import requests
import multiprocessing
import time
start_time = time.time()
def one():
 
    global start_time
    for n in range(1000, 4000):
      answer = requests.post('https://www.guessthepin.com/prg.php', data={'guess': n})
      if "Holy Moley!" not in str(answer.text):
       print("The pin is not", n)
       continue
      print(f"THE PIN IS: {n}")
      end_time = time.time()
      print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time) / 60} minutes")
      sys.exit()
def two():
    
    global start_time
    for n in range(4000, 7000):
      answer = requests.post('https://www.guessthepin.com/prg.php', data={'guess': n})
      if "Holy Moley!" not in str(answer.text):
       print("The pin is not", n)
       continue
      print(f"THE PIN IS: {n}")
      end_time = time.time()
      print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time) / 60} minutes")
      sys.exit()

def three():
    
    global start_time
    for n in range(7000, 10000):
      answer = requests.post('https://www.guessthepin.com/prg.php', data={'guess': n})
      if "Holy Moley!" not in str(answer.text):
       print("The pin is not", n)
       continue
      print(f"THE PIN IS: {n}")
      end_time = time.time()
      print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time) / 60} minutes")
      sys.exit()
def four():
    global start_time
    for n in range(0, 1000):
      zero_thousand = f'{n:04}'
      request = requests.post('https://www.guessthepin.com/prg.php', data={'guess': zero_thousand})
      if "Holy Moley!" not in str(request.text):
       print("The pin is not", zero_thousand)
       continue
      print(f"THE PIN IS: {n}")
      end_time = time.time()
      print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time) / 60} minutes")
      sys.exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=one)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=two)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=three)
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=four)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    print("Done!")
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time)/60} minutes")




So here i wanted to send requests to a website check if the pin is correct and move on. Even though the requests part works when I use multiprocessing and get the correct pin, instead of quitting all the processes, it keeps continuing until it verifies all the numbers.

You will need to send a signal, for example using multiprocessing.Event. All child processes should check if the event is set or not before starting the next iteration, and exits if the event is set.

how would i exit the loop? cause nothing i try ever works

What exactly do you want to do? All your processes end automatically when they have finished running through 1000 iterations. There is no need to use sys.exit(). After the print-statement, the function in the process is finished and the process will close.

there are several functions in my code. I want it so that after the event triggers all my processes stop. Whenever i try to stop them all, it doesn't work. For example, when i find the pin, only one process stops but the rest continue until the iteration is finished.

As an aside, looking at your functions one, two, etc., it appears that multithreading could be used instead of multiprocessing.
I think the simplest solution is to use a multiprocessing pool of size 4 created with multiprocessing.pool.Pool(4). Then you can submit to the pool the 4 "tasks" to be completed specifying a callback to be invoked when a task completes. The first task to complete will call terminate on the pool, which will terminate the other submitted tasks.
I would also suggest that each task execute start_time = time.time() rather than inheriting a global start_time (the global start_time statement in any event is not required), since each task will begin at a different time. And you should not be calling sys.exit(). You should also read PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code.
Update
Since your functions one .. four are identical except for the ranges being searched and four passes a different type of POST argument, these four functions can be replaced by a single function. The worker function also returns True if it find the string being sought:
import time
import requests

USE_THEADING = False

if USE_THREADING:
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
else:
    from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def worker(start, end):
    start_time = time.time()
    for n in range(start, end):
        arg = f'{n:04}' if start == 0 else {'guess': n}
        answer = requests.post('https://www.guessthepin.com/prg.php', data=arg)
        if "Holy Moley!" not in str(answer.text):
            print("The pin is not", n)
            continue
        print(f"THE PIN IS: {n}")
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time) / 60} minutes")
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()

    pool = Pool(4)

    def task_completion(result):
        if result is True:
            # One of the functions has terminated having founf the string:
            pool.terminate()

    pool.apply_async(worker, args=(1000, 4000), callback=task_completion)
    pool.apply_async(worker, args=(4000, 7000), callback=task_completion)
    pool.apply_async(worker, args=(7000, 10000), callback=task_completion)
    pool.apply_async(worker, args=(0, 1000), callback=task_completion)

    # Wait for submitted tasks to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("Done!")
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken: {(end_time - start_time)/60} minutes")


the problem with that is that first, it doesn't execute all the function and if none of the numbers in a function are the pin, it doesn't work. It only executes function number 1. Second of all, I chose multiprocessing cause its faster and I can use 4 processors at a time, but this slows it down a lot. For example, if i ran all my functions then it would take 25 minutes, but when i ran only one function it took 25 mins.

See the update to the answer.

See What should I do when someone answers my question?. You should consider accepting the answer.

my bad im kind of new to stackoverflow

It's not a problem. And accepting an answer is optional.
